# Is there a way to stop saving any data or history in TWA?

Tags: android, webview, chrome-custom-tabs, trusted-web-activity

I'm implementing Trusted Web Activities in my Android project,
and as I understand it keeps data synchronised with Chrome.

Is there a way to make data used inside the app private and not saved -like form fields and history- ?

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible, as opening an Trusted Web Activity in an "Incognito Mode" is not currently supported.